# MS Word VBA attaching a text box to even and odd header

Tags: vba, header, textbox, cpu-word

I have created this code to get my text box in the odd and even headers, but the text box is always attached to the body of the document instead of being in the header.

```
Dim ndx As Integer
Dim line As String
Dim lineChar As Integer
Dim pages As Integer
Dim Box As Shape


'Since the odd/even headers are different, we need to set them twice
For ndx = 1 To 2 'put back to 1 to 2

    If (ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Panes(1).pages.Count >= ndx) Then
  
        Selection.GoTo wdGoToPage, wdGoToAbsolute, ndx
        ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageHeader

        Set HeaderRange = ActiveDocument.Sections.Item(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterEvenPages).Range

        HeaderRange.Text = " "

        If ndx = 1 Then
        
            Set Box = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
                Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
                Left:=InchesToPoints(1), Top:=InchesToPoints(0.5), Width:=InchesToPoints(4.8), Height:=InchesToPoints(0.37))
            
        Else
        
            Set Box = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
                Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
                Left:=300, Top:=50, Width:=500, Height:=20)
            
        End If
   
        
        Box.TextFrame.TextRange.Bold = True
        Box.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 8
        Box.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "This is a sample policy from another school district. Contents do not necessarily reflect official " & _
            vbCrLf & "MSBA policy, represent MSBA legal advice or service, and are not intended for exact replication."
                      
    End If
   
Next ndx
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't working because it adds the text box to the document [`ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox`] instead of the header. The code below works for me.

```
Sub TextBoxInHeader()
    Dim Box As Shape
    Dim ndx As Integer

    For ndx = 1 To 3 Step 2

        With ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(ndx)
            .Range.Text = " "
            If ndx = 1 Then 'Primary (odd pages) header
                Set Box = .Shapes.AddTextbox( _
                    Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
                    Left:=InchesToPoints(1), Top:=InchesToPoints(0.5), Width:=InchesToPoints(4.8), Height:=InchesToPoints(0.37))
            Else    'Even pages header
                Set Box = .Shapes.AddTextbox( _
                    Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
                    Left:=300, Top:=50, Width:=500, Height:=20)
            End If
        End With
   
        With Box.TextFrame.TextRange
            .Bold = True
            .Font.Size = 8
            .Text = "This is a sample policy from another school district. Contents do not necessarily reflect official " & _
                vbCrLf & "MSBA policy, represent MSBA legal advice or service, and are not intended for exact replication."
        End With
                
    Next ndx
End Sub
```

Comment: Timothy Rylatt, I thank you very much. This did what I needed.

Comment: I have to ask for help again. This code puts both text boxes in the first header.

    With ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary)
        Set Box = .Shapes.AddTextbox( ...)
     End With

        With ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterEvenPages)

            Set Box2 = .Shapes.AddTextbox(...) 
        End With

    End If

Comment: @SusanKennedy - please post as a new question so that you can post all the code you are using. The code in my answer works perfectly for me.